# 問い合わせフォームのプレースホルダが数値文字参照になっている

Tags: バグ, デザイン

### 不具合事象

[問い合わせフォーム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)のプレースホルダが数値文字参照になっています。以下は問い合わせページの「トラスト＆セーフティ」の一項目を選択したときのスクリーンショットです。

この画像を見ると、メールアドレス、リンク、検索キーワードなどの入力欄のプレースホルダが数値文字参照になっていることがわかります。これ以外の選択肢においても、同様の問題が発生していることを確認しています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 再現環境

- OS：Windows 10 64-bit
- ブラウザ：Opera One(バージョン: 104.0.4944.36)

Comment: Meta Stack Exchangeで[調査中](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393000/348970)のようです。まずは様子を見て、この手の問題が軽視されているようであれば、日本語版からもエスカレーションしようと思います。